# Can I invite multiple organizations to an existing Board?

Tags: trello

I need to deal with multiple Organizations to clearly show responsibility limits but some need to be able to view Board from other Organizations and I won't be able to manage Members as each organization member list will be evolving on a fast scale.

I tried to add an Organization to a Board already having one but I was only able the change the Organization owning the Board.

My question: Can I invite multiple organizations to an existing Board?

Comment: Would something like in-org 'teams' or read-only board members be useful to you?

Answer (score 2):

No, sorry. To support this, you need to create a new organization that represents the permissions you need for the board.

Comment: That said, you're free to manually invite the members of multiple organizations to the same board.